# R simplifying multiple logical checking

Tags: r

I have this instruction 
`df2<- subset(df1, a == 2208 | a == 123 | a == 1242)`

How can I simplify this instruction if I have let say few ten of checking on `a` ?

EDIT: `a` is a column name in `df1`

Comment: Will there ever be any rows showing true in your example?

Comment: How can a be three different values at the same time?

Comment: We can use `%in%` if it is for the same column. i.e. `subset(df1, a %in% c(2208, 123, 1242))`.  Suppose if it for multiple columns i.e. a, b, c, `Reduce("&",Map("==", df1, c(2208, 123, 1242)))`

Comment: Please consider to provide a reproducible example with expected output

Comment: @docendo discimus `a` is a column name in df1

Comment: @noblabla Actually, what docendo discimus wants to say is that at one time, one row of the data.frame can have only one value for a given column. Either it will be 1 or 2 or 3 or any distinct value for a row. So, this instruction will return a data.frame with no rows.

Comment: @noblabla  I think you want to use `|` rather than `&`.

Comment: @lmo yes, thank you, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on @akrun's use of `%in%`, the standard method for subseting in R is to use `[]`. The syntax for your example would be

```
dfNew <- df[df$a %in% c(2208, 123, 1242),]
```

Note that you could combine this to subset on more than one variable at once.

```
dfNew <- df[df$a %in% c(2208, 123, 1242) & df$b > 10,]
```

where the second condition requires that some variable b must be greater than 10.